# How do you wrap text around a user control?

Tags: user-controls, controls

I need to wrap text around a user control. Specifically, I am displaying an image in a user control. Normally, the align="right" would handle this on an image byu itself. But, put inside a user control, it doesn't seem to flow. I already tried putting the control in a div but this didn't look right either.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
float: right;
```

or

```
float: left;
```

should do it.  I'd just add that CSS to the user control's surrounding DIV.